# Translating "How long does it take to get from <here> to <there>?"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, preguntas, tiempo

What is the most natural and common way to ask how much time it takes to get from one location to another? For example:

- How long does it take to get from Guadalajara to Mexico City?
- How long does it take to get to Los Angeles by car?
- How long does it take to fly to New York from here?
- It's 50 miles away? How long does it take to get there?

Comment: When travelling in Spanish-speaking countries I always said *"¿Cuánto tiempo se necesita para llegar a <there> desde <here>?* -- But I always had doubts that it was the best way...

Comment: I just noticed your question title talks about getting **from A to B** but your examples on talk about getting **to B**. Are both important or just the latter. It would be nice if you could clarify which you need in your question.

Comment: @hippietrail: Both, added another example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just want to add a standard Spanish example, as I see the previous answer is more Mexican-oriented (with all due respect).

- Cuánto **se tarda** en llegar a Los Ángeles en coche?
- Está a 50 millas? Cuánto **se tarda** en llegar?

Also, for differentiation, in Spain we would not replace "cuánto" with "qué tanto" and we would not use "tomar", although we would understand it, of course.

Comment: @c4sh: it should be "qué tanto" rather than "que tanto", and "cuánto" rather than "cuanto".

Answer (score 6):

¿Cuánto tiempo toma llegar a **"lugar"** desde **"lugar"** en **"medio de transporte"**?

- ¿Cuánto tiempo toma llegar a los Angeles en carro?
- ¿Cuánto tiempo
  toma llegar a Nueva York en avión desde aquí?
- ¿Está a 50 millas de
  aquí? ¿Cuánto tiempo toma?

You can use:

1. ¿**Cuánto tiempo toma** llegar a Los Ángeles en carro.?
2. ¿**Cuánto toma** llegar a Los Ángeles en carro.?
3. ¿**Cuánto tiempo tardo** en llegar a Los Ángeles en carro.?
4. ¿**Cuánto tardo** en llegar a Los Ángeles en carro.?
5. You can also replace the **Cuánto** with "**Qué tanto**".

Comment: Also, you can add the *pronominal* form: *¿Cuánto tiempo se tarda en llegar de Los Ángeles a Nueva York?*

Comment: Thanks @Alfredo. Since the OP's sample questions also included a form with an origin and destination would you like to include a translation for that one too? *“How long does it take to get from <here> to <there>?”*

Comment: Is the use of *tomar* in this sense standard Spanish?

Comment: @jrdioko I don't know if it is part of the standard Spanish but it is common in Mexico. For instance you can say: ¿Cuanto tiempo te tomó hacer la tarea?

Comment: @hippietrail done.